# python3 requests hangs when accessing port 25564 or higher on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, port

I have a [simple program](https://github.com/Stehlampe2020/pyfileshare.git) which creates a simple web server at localhost with a random port between 10000 and 65535 (which is the highest unsigned 16-bit integer). You can also specify a port but if you don't know on which port it runs it's hard to find out.
I have written a little helper program that should show every port that's being listened to.
The helper:

```py
import requests
for port in range(10000, 65535):
    try:
        print(port, requests.get("http://localhost:{}".format(port)))
    except Exception as e:
        print("{}: {}".format(type(e).__name__, port), end="\r")
```

I expect it to show `ConnectionError: 10000` and counting up to 65535 and showing any found connections. But it hangs always on port <del>25564</del> 25565, last showing the message for port 25564. And if I do a completely unrelated request to 'http://localhost:25564' or any higher port it hangs.
The script hangs on port 25565 when I start a server on 25564.
Normally if a port has no server listening it will immediately refuse the connection and give a ConnectionError. Above port 25564 it doesn't but just waits until I stop it.

<del>This behaviour seems completely random as port 25564 is unassigned according to [speedguide.net](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=25564).</del>
Port 25565 is the standard MySQL and Minecraft Dedicated Server port (according to [speedguide.net](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=25565)), both of which I haven't running on my machine. Therefore the hang still seems random.

I'm using python3 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Interestingly it didn't fail on my laptop with Linux Mint 21...

As @root requested in the comments, here is the output of `nmap localhost`:

```
Starting Nmap  7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-09-25 11:42 CEST
Host is up (0.00014s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
631/tcp  open  ipp
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
9050/tcp open  tor-socks

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

Just a little note: port 80/tcp is listened on by apache2 with the "You are an idiot" flash animation.

Comment: Please add to your question the output of `nmap localhost`.

Comment: Done. Hope it helps. By the way, hosting on that port works flawlessly. On both devices mentioned above.

Comment: presumably it hangs because it has not failed in the `try` block, so try to deploy a **timer function** to give it, say 5 seconds to connect would resilve the issue.

Comment: @D.L If it doesn't fail it just goes on so the first 15564 ports are being looped through within a few seconds. It only hangs on higher ports than 25564. If you have a simple timer function please add it as an answer so I can change my script to not freeze like that.

Comment: "And if I do a completely unrelated request to 'http://localhost:25564' or any higher port it hangs" - does it happen only on that machine? does it happen if you just make a curl request to e.g. port 30000?  does it happen when your python web server isn't running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, you can try something like this:

You will note that i have added the `timeout` parameter in the `requests`. This units are in seconds. The default timeout is `None`, which means it'll wait (hang) until the connection is closed.

```py
import requests
for port in range(10_000, 65_535):
    try:
        r = requests.get(f'http://localhost:{port}', timeout=5)
        print(port)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'{type(e).__name__}, {port}', end='\r')
```